# Retrive nested array document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
    {

        "id" : "Sir3GHMQ",
        "name" : "Medavakkam",
        "userList" : [ 
            {
                "loginName" : "venkat@gmail.com",
                "role" : "ADMIN"
            }, 
            {
                "loginName" : "sam@gmail.com",
                "role" : "Operator"
            }
        ]
    }


    {

        "id" : "Sir3GHER",
        "name" : "Medavakkam",
        "userList" : [ 
            {
                "loginName" : "venkat@gmail.com",
                "role" : "OPERATOR"
            },
{
                "loginName" : sam@gmail.com",
                "role" : "OPERATOR"
            }
        ]
    }
```

In the collection I need to retrieve documents where `userList. loginame="venkat@gmail.com"` also check where role is "admin". Where role is admin means retrieve all userList:LoginName with their role, else retrieve only userList:loginName with their role, what ever it is.

I tried this:

```
db.Site.aggregate([ 
    { "$match": { "userList.loginName": "venkat@gmail.com" } }, 
    { "$redact": { 
        "$cond": [ 
            { "$eq": [ 
                { "$ifNull" [ "$loginName", "venkat@gmail.com" ] }, 
                "venkat@gmail.com" 
            ] }, 
            "$$DESCEND", 
            "$$PRUNE" 
        ] 
    } } 
])
```

i need output like this

```
{

    "id" : "Sir3GHMQ",
    "name" : "Medavakkam",
    "userList" : [ 
        {
            "loginName" : "venkat@gmail.com",
            "role" : "ADMIN"
        }, 
        {
            "loginName" : "sam@gmail.com",
            "role" : "Operator"
        }
    ]
}


{

    "id" : "Sir3GHER",
    "name" : "Medavakkam",
    "userList" : [ 
        {
            "loginName" : "venkat@gmail.com",
            "role" : "OPERATOR"
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: So you need to find all the documents with `loginName` as `venkat@gmail.com` ? Why not try `db.Site.find({"userList.loginName": "venkat@gmail.com"})` ?

Comment: yes.loginName as venkat@gmail.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this command  ,

```
          db.f.aggregate([{
            $match: {
                "userList.loginName": "venkat@gmail.com"
            }
        }, {
            "$redact": {
                "$cond": [{
                    $or: [{
                        "$eq": [{
                                "$ifNull": ["$loginName", "venkat@gmail.com"]
                            },
                            "venkat@gmail.com"
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "$eq": [{
                            $setIsSubset: [{
                                $literal: [{
                                    loginName: "venkat@gmail.com",
                                    role: "ADMIN"
                                }]
                            }, "$$ROOT.userList"]
                        }, true]
                    }]
                }, "$$DESCEND", "$$PRUNE"]
            }
        }]).pretty()
```

OutputData:

```
      {
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b697e406169b8451ba4cd2"),
    "id" : "Sir3GHMQ",
    "name" : "Medavakkam",
    "userList" : [
            {
                    "loginName" : "venkat@gmail.com",
                    "role" : "ADMIN"
            },
            {
                    "loginName" : "sam@gmail.com",
                    "role" : "Operator"
            }
    ]
   }

  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b74e91c568ace843ee17c1"),
    "id" : "Sir3GHER",
    "name" : "Medavakkam",
    "userList" : [
            {
                    "loginName" : "venkat@gmail.com",
                    "role" : "OPERATOR"
            }
    ]
 }
```

Hope this will help you.

Java code:

```
              MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
              MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
              MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("f");

                List<Document> results = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(new Document("$match",new Document().append("userList.loginName", "venkat@gmail.com")),
                        new Document("$redact", new Document("$cond",
                                Arrays.asList(new Document("$or",Arrays.asList(new Document("$eq",
                                        Arrays.asList(new Document("$ifNull", Arrays.asList("$loginName", "venkat@gmail.com")), "venkat@gmail.com")),new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList(new Document("$setIsSubset", Arrays.asList(new Document("$literal", Arrays.asList(new Document().append("loginName", "venkat@gmail.com").append("role", "ADMIN"))),"$$ROOT.userList")), true)))), 
                                "$$DESCEND", "$$PRUNE")))

            )).into(new ArrayList<Document>());

                for(Document docs: results){
                    System.out.println(docs.toJson());
                }
```

Comment: how i can implement this query in java

Comment: hi @radhaKrishnan i need some mongodb help  can you me your mail id to contact you?

Comment: Sure , radhakrishnan565@gmail.com